How do I make 404s show up as errors or even warnings in locust log output?
I'm trying to understand locust log levels. Why am I only seeing this in DEBUG output?
[2024-05-06 15:25:54,465] e9d5c4e3e3eb/DEBUG/selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection: Remote response: status=404 | data={"value":{"error":"no such element","message":"no such element: Unable to locate element: {\"method\":\"css selector\",\"selector\":\"[id=\"dash_listener\"]\"}\n  (Session info: chrome-headless-shell=124.0.6367.91)","stacktrace":"#0 ........ 

It's hard to debug with all the non error or warn level debug output.
Can I tell locust that 404s are warnings or errors so I can get cleaner output when troubleshooting?

How are you calling selenium? Are you using locust-plugins or something else?

Yes I'm using this https://pypi.org/project/realbrowserlocusts/ which calls selenium.webdriver. Is there a way to globally configure selenium logging for specific calls like this? So a 404 results in a "ERROR" or "WARNING" log?

That project seems really old. I’d probably recommend https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/webdriver_ex.py instead (I’m not actively maintaining that, but at least it isnt 7 years old :)

But how do I get control over the logging of selenium? Does the plugin have to be modified or can you modify the logging of the selenium package globally?

Sorry, I cant speak for realbrowserlocusts at all. with locust-plugins/WebdriverUser a regular locust request event is fired for every call to locust_find_element
